# Java thread exit without warning

Tags: java, multithreading

my java thread exit with any warning. I have no idea why the thread exit. I can't find it in jstack. And it seems the log code hadn't run. My code below:

```
private class WorkThread extends Thread {

    public WorkThread() {
        super("work-thread");
        setDaemon(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("start running thread work-tracker");
        try {
            while (!interrupted()) {
                try {
                    // do something
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    logger.error("ignore all exception", e);
                }
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }                    
            }
        } finally {
            logger.error("work thread exit interrupted status: {}", interrupted());
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot find the log "work thread exit interrupted status" and anything about "work-thread" in the jstack log. any suggestion?

Comment: Are you certain that `interrupted()` ever happens?  Does your main thread actually finish, or does it hang/were you forced to kill the application?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace` use it.

Comment: `System.exit();` will end everything without executing `finally`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i cant find the thread name in jstack log. and, if the thread is interrupted，it should print the log in finally block?

Comment: Yes, if the thread were killed by some method other than `System.exit()` then I would expect the `finally` block to have been hit.  But are you sure this happened?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can find the thread start log. but no finally log. and no thread in jstack. I will check System.exit later. thx

Comment: Call to `interrupted()` method clears *interrupted status* of the thread. Hence, only to check interrupted status of the method better to use `isInterrupted()` method.

Answer (score -1):

```
private class WorkThread extends Thread {

    public WorkThread() {
        super("work-thread");
        setDaemon(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.error("start running thread work-tracker");
        try {
            while (!interrupted()) {
                try {
                    // do something
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    logger.error("ignore all exception");
                }
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        } finally {
            logger.error("work thread exit interrupted status: {}" +interrupted());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that System.out is better than exception-logging?

Comment: sorry, I just replaced it, the thread will never be interrupted in your code

Comment: Ok, now please explain why repasting the OP's code and moving the call to interrupt() outside of the try-catch somehow an answer to OP's question. The questions states that the thread is somehow being interrupted; not that the OP wants to interrupt it from within.

Comment: no, I moved Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); out of the catch block, thus the thread will be interrupted